# How can I run code before the process exits?

Tags: process, ocaml

I want to run code to flush data to disk when the current process exits normally. I don't mind if this code also runs when the process terminates abnormally.

I tried using [Gc.finalise](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Gc.html) but it appears finalisers are not always run.

Does OCaml have something like Python's [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) or Node's `process.on('exit')`?

Comment: You need to handle signals I guess: https://ocaml.github.io/ocamlunix/signals.html

Comment: You meant "does OCaml have something like Python's atexit or Node's process.on('exit')" right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml does have an `at_exit` function.
From the [doc](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html#at_exit):

> val at_exit : (unit -> unit) -> unit
>
> Register the given function to be called at program termination time.
> The functions registered with at_exit will be called when the program does
> any of the following:
>
> - executes exit
> - terminates, either normally or because of an uncaught exception
> - executes the C function caml_shutdown. The functions are called in 'last in, first out' order: the function most recently added with at_exit is called first.

Comment: [`Fun.protect`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Fun.html) may also be useful.